# Is this an elder or what is the shrub with red berries?

Tags: identification

I have this shrub (of 3 meters height) in my garden and only realized now that its berry might be an elder. I saw some images when searching the internet and the leave and the fruit resembles but it might be a false friend.

Is this an elder? If not, what is it and is it edible? (**click of a larger version of the images**)

[image]
[image] 
[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That looks like a Juneberry (Amelanchier). The berries will become a deep purple, and they are edible. Some trees/shrubs have fruit that is absolutely delicious and tastes a bit like a blueberry - others have fruit that is not so tasty. Hope yours is a tasty one and that you're able to try the fruit before the birds get them. I have two shrubs in my yard and have been outwitted by the birds for two years in a row now.

Comment: I think you're right Michelle, serviceberrys have a prominent calyx this is seen in the picture

Comment: Yes, and what I've always heard is that there are no poisonous berries with a calyx, which (assuming it is true) is helpful to know.